# В чем ошибка? Обясните пожалуйста, новичок

Tags: php, база-данных, ооп, pdo

Присутствующие ошибки:

> ```
> Notice
>   : Undefined index: user_surname ; undefined index: email и подобные 
> А также : 
>  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on null in  
>  "место файла" Stack trace: #0 "место ошибки - $statment -> bindParam(":user_name", $user_name);"
>  "место файла": include_once() #1 {main} "место ошибки где файл соединен через include_once в файле с формой"
>   thrown in
> ```

```
 <?php 

      $db_host = 'localhost'; 
      $db_user = 'root';
      $db_password = 'Sanzharplay13';
      $db_name = 'users';
      $charset = 'utf8mb4';


      $user_name = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["user_name"]));
      $user_surname = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["user_surname"]));
      $email =  trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]));
      $user_password = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["user_password"]));


      $dsn = "mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=$charset";



      $options = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,  
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,  
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,  
      ];  


      try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_password, $options);
      } catch (\PDOException $e) {
         throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
        }


        $sql = "INSERT INTO `user-reg` (username, usersurname, email, password)VALUES(:user_name, :user_surname, :email, :user_password)";
        $statment -> bindParam(":user_name", $user_name);
        $statment -> bindParam(":user_surname", $user_surname);
        $statment -> bindParam(":email", $email);
        $statment -> bindParam(":user_password", $user_password);
        $statment = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $statment -> execute();

    ?>
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что здесь есть ошибка?

Comment: а, ну да. и еще ведь prepare нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На будущее, сообщение об ошибке надо писать в вопросе.

Ошибка в тексте запроса. Имя поля, содержащее нестандартные символы необходимо брать в обратные кавычки

```
INSERT INTO `user-reg`
```

Comment: Все проблема наконец-то решена. Оказалось что просто   $statment = $pdo->prepare($sql); -- нужно разместить до методов bindparam().Я так уже делал, но я просто забыл обновить страницу  как это сделал.Спасибо всем кто мне  помог. Особенно спасибо Ипатьеву помог с PDO